# 'libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Tags: shared-library, android-studio

I tried to install apk file but I can't.

```
/home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
bash: /home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/: Is a directory
```

```
./adb install'/home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/mobogenie_1028.apk'
bash: ./adb: No such file or directory
```

```
./adb installmobogenie_1028.apk' 
>

cd /home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
./adb installFacebook.apk 
./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: @Fabby the OP is trying to use the android debugger _on Ubuntu_. The error is about a library missing _from Ubuntu_, the solution posted below involves installing the missing library, once more, _on Ubuntu_ :).

Answer (score 6):

Try these commands:

```
cd /home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
```

```
./adb install mobogenie_1028.apk
```

```
./adb 'installmobogenie_1028.apk'
```

What was wrong?

1. Needed to be `cd`. You weren't actually changing directory.
2. You had no space after install and the path. It may have been causing an issue?
3. You had an extra quote at the end, which was causing the `>`. Bash was expecting more input.

   On top of that, you hasn't changed directories with command 1, so there was no file in that location.

---

Update. Per the edit, you need this answer:

> [libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11471722/libstdc-so-6-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directory)

Run this command:

```
apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```

And then the commands I have already said above:

My pronouns are He / Him

Comment: drmohammed@drmohammed-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ cd /home/drmohammed/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/
drmohammed@drmohammed-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ 
drmohammed@drmohammed-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$ ./adb installFacebook.apk
./adb: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
drmohammed@drmohammed-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~/workspace/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools$

Comment: No, I can't read output pasted into a comment. Please edit into the main question.

Comment: @MohammedElsayed Please follow this link: http://askubuntu.com/posts/613723/edit, paste in your code and then I can help.

Comment: @MohammedElsayed I can't help if you don't do what I've said...

Comment: @Tim I believe [this is your output](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613734/when-i-try-to-to-install-apk-this-happen?noredirect=1).

Comment: Why did you vote to close this? As far as I can tell, and as suggested by your solution, this is an Ubuntu issue and not Android.

Comment: @terdon well directly it was unclear what you were asking, and because of that appeared to be about android. I'll vote to reopen,

Comment: I wasn't asking anything :) I just saw [this meta post](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14025/85695).

Answer (score 0):

i have this same message error to run emulators and solved like this :

```
sudo ln -sf   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++ <your-android-sdk-path>/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6
```